# how to calculate total loss using losses of batches

Tags: neural-networks

I want to train a neural network in pytorch and I want to check it's total loss  but I get gpu memory error. so I can't fit whole train dataset into gpu and calculate the total loss of train dataset, but I have no problem calculating losses of batches, so is there any way to calculate whole dataset loss using losses of batches?

Comment: Getting a memory error sounds like a programming problem. The direct way to solve it is to get more memory. Another way to solve it is to not put all of the data in the GPU at once, but only batch-by-batch. Is there a reason you can't add up the losses of the batches to compute the total loss?

Comment: HI @Sycorax I know I won't be able to add gpu memory so I want a mathematical to get the correct way  or approximation which is more mathematically accepted to compute total loss using batch losses.


if you meant getting simple average of losses of batches by`can't add up the losses of the batches` actually I can!!

btw I guess you have lots of experiences using neural networks, haven't you ever faced a big network that you can't put it once in gpu then to calculate loss what do you do in that cases? why others don't face such? I mean why Im the first person to ask for this!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Just move the batches to GPU as needed instead of putting them all there at once. Then you just accumulate the loss as you train.

Comment: I have tried it and average is much closer (not totally same) to that but anyway thank you

Comment: What do you mean? It’s common practice to calculate the loss batch wise, e.g., passing 32 samples at a time.

Comment: @MarcelB Yes, I know that. OP is asking specifically about an out of memory error arising from shipping the whole dataset to the GPU which has less memory than main system memory.

Comment: Was addressing OP :-) because he seemed quite unconvinced about what’s going on

Comment: @MarcelB you can make that clear using `@name` syntax or just writing a person’s handle.

Comment: @MarcelB I don't know maybe calculating loss using batches is a common practice but I have not seen in examples. what's your opinion between taking average or summing up losses of batches? and would you please tell me what is OP?